# Unity movement issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem in unity where when I move my character it stops moving and I have to move to a different direction and then return to the original direction to be able to move here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed=5f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Debug.Log(horizontal);
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity= new Vector2(speed*horizontal,rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

_ The horizontal input works normally when the problem happen _ There is no specific location where the character gets stops
What can I do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure, but it almost sounds like an input device issue, if the character is able to move in a direction for a while, but randomly stops at some point, requiring you to essentially "refresh" the input, by giving it a different direction before going back to the original.

I would try printing `horizontal` to the console somewhere in your FixedUpdate function, to see if you're actually getting non-zero values when your player stops moving.

I can't really help any more without knowing about what your input method is.

Comment: I tried it works well when the problem happens the values are non-zero